# Sklearn's Affinity Propagation, good dependents bad exemplars

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to use sklearn's affinity propagation implementation for a fairly easy cluster, however, I am getting some funky results. I was trying to use AP with 300 clusters of 3 points each and it failed miserably so I tried a seemingly easy clustering problem of 5 gaussian distributed clusters with 100 points each. The resulting graph is linked below. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

[AP plot](https://github.com/NathanWendt/Random_Python/blob/master/bad_AP.png)

I followed @Anony-Mousse's response from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087793/change-in-preference-value-does-not-affect-the-results-of-affinity-propagation-c), however, increasing the damping and max iterations did not really help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from itertools import cycle

n_per_cluster = 100
n_clusters = 5
n_total = n_per_cluster*n_clusters

x = np.empty(n_total)
y = np.empty(n_total)
labels = np.empty(n_total)
count = 0
for i in range(n_clusters):
    xseed = np.random.random()*100
    yseed = np.random.random()*100
    normX = np.random.normal(xseed,1,n_per_cluster)
    normY = np.random.normal(yseed,1,n_per_cluster)
    normCount = 0
    for j in range(n_per_cluster):
        x[count] = normX[normCount]
        y[count] = normY[normCount]
        labels[count] = i
        normCount+=1
        count+=1

#print(labels)
#print(x, y)
# plt.scatter(x,y)
# plt.show()
preference = -50
max_iter = 1000
xy = np.column_stack((x,y))
af = AffinityPropagation(damping = 0.9, preference = preference, verbose = True, max_iter = max_iter).fit(xy)
_exemplars_index = af.cluster_centers_indices_
_labels = af.labels_
_n_cluster = len(_exemplars_index)

plt.close('all')
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmyk')
for k,col in zip(range(_n_cluster),colors):
    class_members = labels == k #error check
    exemplars = xy[_exemplars_index[k]]
    plt.plot(xy[class_members, 0], xy[class_members,1], col + '.')
    plt.plot(exemplars[0], exemplars[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
    for x in xy[class_members]:
        plt.plot([exemplars[0], x[0]], [exemplars[1], x[1]], col)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % _n_cluster)
plt.show()
```

It is getting the clusters correct, but the exemplars are across the screen. This is a pretty straight forward clustering problem so I imagine it is user error but I haven't figured it out yet. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should have tried a parametric sweep before posting. Apparently, AP is just highly sensitive to metric data. I got decent results at preference = -100, damping =0.95, and 1500 iterations.